# Cannot show the "block" by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot show the block "login" after the page has loaded.
I already tried using `visibility` or `display` to make the "block" hidden or not.

And already tried to put the script part into different place:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/common.css">
  <style>
    .login {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function showlogin() {
      document.getElementById("logvid").getElementByClassName("login").style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>

  <title>City's Video</title>
</head>

<body onload="showlogin">

  <div id="logvid">
    <div class="login">
      <form method="post" action="home.html">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"> <input type="reset" value="reset">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClassName returns an array-like object of all elements which have all of the given class names. 
so you have to select the div like this:

`document.getElementsByClassName("login")[0].style.display ='block';`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

and you need to call functions with parentheses:
`<body onload="showlogin()">`

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) would return a collection of [HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). So, we need to iterate over the collection or be more specific on which element is needed.

Alternative approach would be to use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Sample snippet below:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelectorAll("#logvid > .login").forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
    element.style.border = "1px solid green";
  });
}
```

```css
.login {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="logvid">
  <div class="login">
    <form method="post" action="home.html">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br> Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"> <input type="reset" value="reset">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```